# How can I let multiple Java scripts to run concurrently in Frida?

Tags: javascript, android, penetration-testing, frida, penetration-tools

I want to bypass root detection, certificate pinning, and a crc integrity check for an android app using Frida. I can't run more than 1 script at once, is there any solution?

Comment: Running multiple scripts in Frida is possible. I usually doe this via Frida Python binding, not sure if or how this also works with the command-line version. What have you already tried?

Answer (score 5):

```
frida -U -f [APP_ID] -l script1.js -l script2.js
```

you can try this too

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate all scripts into one file and load is the trivial (and probably good enough) answer.

I have another suggestion that you can do even without a computer, just put text editor on your device and get a bluetooth keyboard.

`frida-inject` which can be downloaded from [frida release page](https://github.com/frida/frida/releases)

Push `frida-inject` & the scripts to the device and execute the following that iterates scripts , inject them to the process and exists.

`for f in $(ls /sdcard/scripts/*js) do; ./frida-inject -p $(pidof com.app.name) -s $f --eternalize`

[frida-inject options](https://github.com/frida/fridacore/blob/master/inject/inject.vala#L12)

Comment: I would assume that concatenating will not work in case multiple scripts define `rpc.exports` methods or have other methods of the same name.

Comment: we can write something for that.. that will replace duplicate names.. if needed :)